# Why does npm flash "verb" and "sill" while installing things?

Tags: node.js, npm

I'd like to understand what is intended to be communicated by the words "verb" and "sill" when installing node modules via npm:

```
⋊> ~/t/quill on develop ◦ npm install                                                                                                                                  15:35:02
⸨      ░░░░░░░░░░░░⸩ ⠙ fetchMetadata: sill mapToRegistry uri https://registry.npmjs.org/big.js
```

The `sill` right before `mapToRegistry` also changes to `verb` and back again. What do these mean?

Comment: The worst part - highlighting those damn words - highly sill of them I must say.

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be absent when `npm config get loglevel` = notice

Answer (score 90, accepted):

I believe this is referring to the `silly` (`sill`) and `verbose` (`verb`) log levels for `npm install`. [See changelog here](https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/d46015256941ddfff1463338e3e2f8f77624a1ff/changelogs/CHANGELOG-3.md#better-layout).

I am not quite sure how it ascertains which to use, but it is for the npm log files to enable easier debugging for developers.

Comment: IMO, "silly" is not a great name but it provides some intuition, on the other hand, shortening it to "sill" is pointlessly obscuring.

Comment: it means so extremely verbose that it's silly. cf "ludicrous speed"

Comment: <rant> "shortening it to "sill" is pointlessly obscuring" - this is apotheosis of what the entire node.js and angular and many others are about - antinomy of simplicity. Makes me feel sick whenever I have to touch it. </rant>

Comment: probably the npm devs were all nooobs

Comment: That there are 9 log levels is silly. That the default log level is the highest one, and yet you often have no clue what happened when there's a problem, is silly. And of course, that the log level is called "silly" is silly. Npm developers were not the brightest, although I'm sure they thought they were.

Answer (score 34):

`sill` shows log level is `silly` in which almost anything is logged. `verb` indicates `verbose` log level that shows log messages a little bit less than `silly` but more than `info`. Regarding the `npm` [official documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config), it has following log levels that are sorted from the least log messages to the most ones:

- silent
- error
- warn
- notice
- http
- timing
- info
- verbose
- silly